# App aproval with partner created enterprise

Tags: android-management-api

i'm creating EMM-managed enterprise. This is the recommended method (no signup page nor google account required)
https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise#emm-managed_enterprises

but, with this enterprise, end user have no IT admin account to connect to managed google play on https://play.google.com/work

what is the correct  way to approve applications with this type of enterprises?

Answer (score 0):

[EMM Managed enterprise](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise#emm-managed_enterprises) is no longer the recommended method to create an enterprise, Instead, we suggest starting a [Customer-managed enterprises](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise#customer-managed_enterprises).

Additionally, with Android Management API any application added under the application [policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#applicationpolicy) behaves based on the configured `installType`. The [play store mode](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#playstoremode) policy determines the behavior of the apps on the device play store.
You will still need to follow all of the policy distribution steps mentioned in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps).